# How to use a local file path in expo-ev?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

How to use a local file path in expo-ev? for example in iOS /Users/jamess/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6B345354-6F3456-4534535A-5353454-9814353456F/data/Containers/Data/Application/D34535D5-E7A5-4F35354F-B42342B-7223424535352/Documents/video5_g243f4.mp4

How use this path and display video using expo-av? is it possible to do that? i also tried normal uri one

```
  <Video
           source={require('/Users/jamess/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6B345354-6F3456-4534535A-5353454-9814353456F/data/Containers/Data/Application/D34535D5-E7A5-4F35354F-B42342B-7223424535352/Documents/video5_g243f4.mp4 ')}
            resizeMode="cover"
            repeat
            shouldPlay
            style={styles.backgroundVdeo}
        />
```

Comment: did you find solution for this quesetion ?

Comment: @AmirFoghel yes use react-native-video package